# Compiled Lua project crashes lightroom 3

Tags: lua, lightroom

I wrote an exporter plugin for LightRoom 3 and 4. The code was compiled with SDK-4 using the windows version of Luac version 5.2.1. The compiled project works fine with LR4 but crashes when attempting to use the plugin for a second time [in LR3].

My intuition tells me that I need to (a) compile with an earlier version of Lua (b) with SDK-3.

Can anyone confirm which version of Lua and SDK should work with the latest version of LR3?

Comment: Does LightRoom use Lua 5.2 at all?

Comment: @lhf my export plugin, was compiled(lua5.2.1) and tested with LR4+SDK4. It was confirmed to work on mac and windows LR4 installations.

Comment: "Lightroom 4 uses version 5.1.4 of the Lua language." http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/photoshoplightroom/pdfs/lr4/lightroom-sdk-guide.pdf

Comment: "Lightroom 3.0 uses version 5.1.2 of the Lua language." -- SDK-3

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @lhf for pointing out that the SDK-4 had the language info in the PDF.  Since I had the PDF for SDK-3 I checked the same section of the DOC. Voila, the same info was there.

```
"Lightroom 4 uses version 5.1.4 of the Lua language."
"Lightroom 3.0 uses version 5.1.2 of the Lua language."
```

** special thanks to @lhf!